# Embed Vimeo Bootstrap 3.0

Tags: embed, vimeo, twitter-bootstrap-3

Question says it all,how is it possible to embed a vimeo video in bootstrap 3.0 ?

Example Code:

```
<div class="container">
   <section class="row">
      <div class="span6">
         <div class="flex-video widescreen"><iframe src="//player.vimeo.com/video/71876963" width="500" height="281" frameborder="0" webkitallowfullscreen mozallowfullscreen allowfullscreen></iframe></div>
         </div>
       <div class="span6">
        ...
      </div>
    </section>
</div>
```

Is unfortunately not working.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Please try this code, it works in bootply

```
<div class="container">
 <div class="row">
 <div class="span6">
 <div class="flex-video widescreen" style="margin: 0 auto;text-align:center;">
 <iframe allowfullscreen="" src="http://player.vimeo.com/video/71876963" frameborder="0" width="500" height="281"></iframe>

  </div> 


   </div>
   </div>
   </div>
```

Comment: In case i need to use it within a pop-up box,should i only include the iframe section ?

Comment: u mean boostrap's modal by pop up box?

Comment: exactly,i need to have a pop up box when an image is clicked ,and then inside the pop up box i need a vimeo video embedded

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple solution that works for me, tested in Bootstrap 3.0:

```
<div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9">
    <iframe src="https://player.vimeo.com/video/71876963"></iframe>
</div>
```

Comment: Code-only answers are not very helpful to users who come to this question in the future. Please edit your answer to explain why your code solves the original problem